# Why does committed heap memory decrease from 4G to 3.86G?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, decrease-key

Tomcat runs in a virtual machine. I monitored a sudden decrease in the JVM committed heap memory from 4G to 3.86G. This causes FULL GC. I want to know why and when JVM does it?

Comment: jdk1.7.0_79:

using thread-local object allocation.
Parallel GC with 4 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 0
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 100
   MaxHeapSize      = 4294967296 (4096.0MB)
   NewSize          = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 536870912 (512.0MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 536870912 (512.0MB)
   G1HeapRegionSize = 0 (0.0MB)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include updates.

Comment: It probably is the other way around.  The Full GC caused the committed memory decrease.  I expect that GC has released some memory back to the OS.  Why?   Because, the GC decided *current* usage patterns do not require / justify use of that much memory.  (My recollection is that this only happens after a Full GC, and it takes a few Full GCs for the GC to decide to do this.)

Comment: Also - you should upgrade your Java installation.  Java 7 is 4 *years* beyond end-of-life.

Comment: Java 7 has not way to release some memory back to the OS